# Visual/intuitive proof of why $\sum k^3 = (\sum k)^2$, where $k$ goes from 1 to $n$?

Tags: summation

I understand that one could prove this by first proving the analytic expressions of the sigma terms through induction, and then square the $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k$ term to show LHS = RHS.

Are there any other easier to understand (preferably visual) proofs one could show?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number)?

Comment: [This is also worth a look.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/24828#24828)